# E-Commerce, how to calculate price on 3 dimensional matrix?

Tags: excel, e-commerce, theory

I have a product that we wish to have a quote form for. the form has:

1 - Quantity
2 - Size
3 - Option Extra 1
4 - Option Extra 2 etc..

The Quantity and Size determine the cost of the optional extras. E.g to "paint" the item as an optional extra will need to calculate based on the quantity and size.

Whats the best way to build a pricing matrix to support this structure? I can do an excel table with Quantity & Size, but I don't know how to represent a number of option elements that depend on these 2 dimensions.

Any help much appreciated..

Comment: That's like [shoving a square peg into a round hole](http://howtogeekon.com/2010/05/18/fit/square-peg-in-a-round-hole_0565/) -- perhaps a multi-level "pivot table" can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it takes twice as much paint to paint two widgets than it does one, this is just

```
$(total) = $(each) * quantity
```

For the size, you'll need a number to scale the cost.  The amount of paint needed is proportional to the surface area to paint, so in this case

```
$(total) = $(per sq ft) * total sq ft
```

But you can roll the first function into the second, right?  Just treat two widgets as one with twice the square footage.

So ultimately you'll need some estimate of cost per sq ft of surface area to paint.  Calculate the total square footage of all of the widgets you're selling, and multiply this by the cost per square foot to paint, and you have the price of the extra.

Comment: I thought that, I just think there becomes a discount on "paint" if it reaches a certain size. That's the tricky part. If that isn't possible or too hard, will need to have it scale as a flat number?

Comment: You can make the function more complicated if you want, like, I don't know, $0.50 per square foot up to 1000 sq ft, $0.45 per sq ft for the next 1000, etc. Add in a flat setup fee for labor, paint mixing, etc. Bottom line is that the true cost is some fixed costs plus the costs of materials, and the latter is based on how much of the stuff you're using. That can be encapsulated in a formula assuming that you can estimate from the items how much in materials you'll need, like square footage of paintable area.

Comment: I'm just making up what might be a reasonable model. I don't really know your business. :) But you can use some conditionals: 0.50*totalSqFt + 0.45*(totalSqFt - 1000). Add the second term if totalSqFt > 1000, otherwise add zero.  It's like calculating a graduated income tax.